# SQL Command Gives "Unknown Column" Error

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to deal with a massive spam attack on my forum by deleting all messages with references to certain drugs like "Ultram", etc.

I have the following command:

```
DELETE FROM `database_name`.`mybb_posts` WHERE `mybb_posts`.`message` LIKE `%Ultram%`;
```

mybb_posts is the name of the table.  message is the column, and I want to delete any row where the message has an instance of the word Ultram.  Any help please?

Comment: Please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mybb_posts`

Comment: Your SQL query has been executed successfully

Comment: I meant, please edit your question and add the structure of the table as reported by the SHOW command.

Comment: Can you please paste the exact error you are getting as well as the table structure?

Comment: try `describe your_table_name` using your table name for your_table_name

Comment: Table mybb_posts  CREATE TABLE `mybb_posts` ( `pid` int(10) unsign...)

Comment: i don't see the message column?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
DELETE FROM `database_name`.`mybb_posts` WHERE message LIKE "%Ultram%";
```

or

```
DELETE FROM `database_name`.`mybb_posts` WHERE message LIKE '%Ultram%';
```

or

```
USE database_name;
DELETE FROM mybb_posts WHERE message LIKE '%Ultram%';
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column '%Ultram%' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of these: (notice the change of ` to ')

```
DELETE FROM `database_name`.`mybb_posts` WHERE `mybb_posts`.`message` LIKE '%Ultram%';

DELETE FROM `database_name`.`mybb_posts` WHERE `message` LIKE '%Ultram%';
```

MySQL considers anything inside "`" as a database or table or column name. Hence you should use either single-quotes (') or double quotes(") for values.